# PHP unlink file Вернуть состояние

Tags: php, apache

Товарищи вот при работе с базой данных есть транзакция `beginTransaction`.
Можно либо откатить изменения, если что-то пошло не так `rollback`
или можно фиксировать новое состояние базы данных `commit`.

Так вот, есть ли что-то похожее при удалении файла с сервера при помощи php?
Типо сделал `unlink('/url/file');`

Дальше идет `остальной код` и где-то что-то пошло не так, и надо вернуть эти файлы, типо отмена удаления. Есть что-то такое? Удаляю через `foreach` несколько файлов.

Comment: Может, перемещайте во временную папку перед окончательным удалением?

Comment: Штатного вроде ничего нет. Правильно говорят, копируте файл перед удалением в папочку, а потом уже можно настроить удаление по cron по истечению, скажем, недели.

Comment: Мм, понял. Спасибо за хорошую идею

Answer (score 0):

unlink по сути удаляет файл сразу и навсегда, но можно передвинуть файл и проработать полезную нагрузку.

```
$file = "MyFile.txt";
$last_abort_state = false;
try {
    $tmp = tempnam(); # Временное имя для файла, в папке tmp если не указанно иначе
    $last_abort_state = ignore_user_abort(true); # Не останавливать скрипт если юзер отвалился.
    rename($file, $tmp);

    # Полезная нагрузка

    unlink($tmp); # commit
} catch (Exception $err) {
    rename($tmp, $file); # rollback
}
ignore_user_abort($last_abort_state); # Возвращаем предыдущее состояние abort
```

Comment: В общем случае `unlink` удаляет __имя файла__. И если у файла нет других имен или другой процесс не читает из него что-либо, то файл считается удаленным. Можно например создать жесткую ссылку на файл, удалить файл исходный, но по жесткой ссылке останется тот же самый контент.